# A problem on inter-relation between the inverses of a matrix .

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-decomposition

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ 
We know that the set 
$S = \{ $$
             \begin{bmatrix} 
              x & x \\
              x & x \\
             \end{bmatrix}
             $$ | x \in \mathbb R-\{0\} \}$, forms a group under matrix multiplication, with the element $$
             \begin{bmatrix} 
              1/2 & 1/2 \\
              1/2 & 1/2 \\
             \end{bmatrix}
             $$ as identity and 
            $$
         \begin{bmatrix} 
          1/{4x} & 1/{4x} \\
          1/{4x} & 1/{4x} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
         $$ as inverse for each element .
Point to note that each element of $S$ is singular .

Is there any underlying relationship between the standard inverse of a matrix and the group theoretic inverse of the element $$
         \begin{bmatrix} 
          x & x \\
          x & x \\
         \end{bmatrix}
         $$ ???

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ I found the eigenvalues $0 \ and \ 2x$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $(1, -1)$ and $(1,1)$ for each matrix in $S$ and hence we can find an orthogonal eigenvector basis for $\mathbb R^2$ and more interestingly, each element of S can be decomposed uniquely into two invertible matrices ;
$$
         \begin{bmatrix} 
          x & x \\
          x & x \\
         \end{bmatrix}
         =
         \begin{bmatrix} 
          x & 0 \\
          0 & x \\
         \end{bmatrix} + 
         \begin{bmatrix} 
          0 & x \\
          x & 0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
         $$

Does this fact imply anything ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f\colon \mathbb R\setminus 0\to S$ given by
$$
f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}x/2&x/2\\x/2&x/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $f$ is seen to be a group isomorphism from the multiplicative group of non-zero real numbers to $S$.

In other words, the group is not really using any of the 2-dimensional matrix structure: it is just a copy of our usual group of multiplicative non-zero reals. As you pointed out, none of the matrices in $S$ have a matrix inverse. As such, there is no direct relation between matrix inverses and group inversion in $S$.

By the way, a change of basis might make the situation clearer: this is effectively the same thing as considering the group of matrices
$$
T=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\colon x\in \mathbb R\setminus 0\right\}
$$
again under matrix multiplication. None of these matrices are invertible, yet we still have a group inverse given by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x^{-1}&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Sir, then what about this typical fact of having the relation $$
             \begin{bmatrix} 
              x & x \\
              x & x \\
             \end{bmatrix}
             =
             \begin{bmatrix} 
              x & 0 \\
              0 & x \\
             \end{bmatrix} + 
             \begin{bmatrix} 
              0 & x \\
              x & 0 \\
             \end{bmatrix}
             $$ which in general all matrices may not possess , (such a beautiful additional decomposition) ???

Comment: The group operation is matrix multiplication, so it is not clear what significance an additive decomposition has on the problem...